# How to find API from website for selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

There is a website "https://www.1parrainage.com". From there, I need to retrieve the GET and POST request to login automatically with my ID. The Selenium and Request libraries are ready, but for the Request library, you need to know the API of this site. Then you can write "`requests.get (api).()`"

Could you please help me to find the API in such open sites?

I tried to track it through dev tools > Network in the browser,  but it is not possible to follow the link

I tried to track it through dev tools > Network in the browser

Comment: You just copy the API from the network DOM sheet, and utilize those APIs with Selenium code.  even though I am not confident with this answer but always trying will give other ways of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium allows you to interact with the UI of a website. Therefore, you can directly interact with the login screen and login there. You don't need the API for that. If the page does not offer an official API, it is not that simple to "reverse engineer" a login process. It's worth noting that reverse engineering web interactions can be against a website's terms of service and might not always work as intended.

Comment: It's worth noting  also that the use of selenium for web interactions can be against a website's terms of service.